# GEKKO: count ocurrences in an 2D array as condition

Tags: python, constraints, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I have a grid of 9 points in the xy coordinate system with following coordinates (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3).

The grid looks like the following:

[image: see picture 1]

I would like to solve follwoing non-linear integer optimization problem using GEKKO:
[image: Non-linear optimization problem] where i=1,2,3 and j=1,2,3. In other words, the pairs (xi, yi) can only appear once in each point of the grid.

So far I wrote this piece of code, but I don't know how to define the constraints in GEKKO.

```
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO() # create GEKKO model
w13 = ((x1-x3)**2+(y1-y3)**2)**0.5
w57 = ((x5-x7)**2+(y5-y7)**2)**0.5
obj_fun = 2*w13 + 3*w57
m.Minimize(obj_fun)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()
```

**Edit:** Inspired by John's comment, I've tried out this code

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
m.options.SOLVER = 1

b = m.Array(m.Var, (3,3), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
k = m.Array(m.Var, (3))
k[0].value = 1
k[1].value = 2
k[2].value = 3
x1 = m.sum(b.dot(k))
x3 = m.sum(b.dot(k))
x5 = m.sum(b.dot(k))
x7 = m.sum(b.dot(k))
y1 = m.sum(b.dot(k))
y3 = m.sum(b.dot(k))
y5 = m.sum(b.dot(k))
y7 = m.sum(b.dot(k))

w13 = ((x1-x3)**2+(y1-y3)**2)**0.5
w57 = ((x5-x7)**2+(y5-y7)**2)**0.5
obj_fun = 2*w13 + 3*w57
m.Equation(m.sum(b) <= 1)
m.Equation(m.sum(b) >= 1)
m.Minimize(obj_fun)
m.solve()
```

,but unfortunately I got an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arman.Kohnic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 23, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\...\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py", line 25, in __len__
    return len(self.value)
  File "C:\Users\...\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py", line 144, in __len__
    return len(self.value)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Could you spell out the constraints and variables in more detail? It isn't obvious how `x5`, `x7`, `y5`, and `y7` are defined. How many variables are in the problem? You can use `Z = m.Array(m.Var,(3,3),integer=True)` to define a 3x3 matrix of values that are integers. The `m.sum()` function should also help with defining the constraints.

Comment: Hey John, let me explain the problem in a more detail. So the 9 points in the grid are 9 shelves in a warehouse. We have 9 items that we have to place onto each shelve, but with the constraint that on one shleve there cannot be more than 1 item. The warehouse employee is picking items by going from one item to another. What we want to minimize is the path that the employee covers while picking up those items. Therefore the problem is to find the distirbution of the items in the grid (their (x,y) coordinates) such that the covered path is minimum. I will continue the explanation in the next com

Comment: Continuing the previous comment...Thus there are 18 variables (9 x-variables and 9 y-variables) and 9 constraints (1 constraint for each shelve, i.e. each item has a unique (x,y) point in the grid). The objective function can be any path that the employee covers, but for the sake of simplicity I took the objective function to be the path from the item with coordinate (x2,y2) to (x3,y3) (2 times), and from item with coordinate (x5,y5) to (x7,y7) (3 times). I hope this brings more clarity to the problem.